# How to track a rotary gesture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, gesture-recognition

I would like to track a ONE finger rotary gesture how do I intercept that gesture?

To give you a visual example: the same gesture that you would have used with an old disc phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest the `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` class?  As long as you don't need to support < iOS 3.2 it will save you much headache trying to build your own gesture recognition mechanism.

[Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIRotateGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thank you for you answer however as far as I know that api handles two touch points, not one, as you would do for a dial, say an on old phone dial. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct.  I would recommend taking a look at the documentation for Implementing a Custom Gesture Recognizer.  The documentation shows how to make a checkmark gesture recognizer and it should be fairly simple to modify that to make a gesture recognizer that would recognize circular motion. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW25